# How to draw a Component on a canvas in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I need to draw a React component on a canvas. This code works to add a svg:

```js
const svg = "mysvgpath";

function draw(ctx) {
  const path = new Path2D(svg);
  ctx.fill(path);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.restore();
}

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth);
    draw(ctx);
  }, []);
  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={500} height={500} />;
}
```

Would it be possible to add a component `<Test/>` instead? (This code doesn't work so far, of course)

```js
function Test (){
 return <div style={{height:200, width:200, background:"red"}}/>
}

function draw(ctx) {
  const path = new Path2D(<Test/>);
  ctx.fill(path);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.restore();
}

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth);
    draw(ctx);
  }, []);
  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={500} height={500} />;
}
```

Here is a sandbox in case you want to try it: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-state-change-in-react-gpty8?file=/src/App.js:51-1553

EDIT:
I have managed to obtain [Object, Object] when drawing the  component this way. It's still bad, but if someone knows how to transform this [Object, Object] is a real html node, it's done. I rely on you!

```js
const data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">' +
   '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
      '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:50px">' +
         <Test/> +
      '</div>' +
   '</foreignObject>' +
'</svg>'
function draw(ctx) {

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
         var img1 = new Image();
         var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
         var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
         img1.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 25, 70);
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
         }
         img1.src = url;

  ctx.save();
  ctx.restore();
}
```